# loop in all property of model in typescript and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

i have a generic model for get all items from Schema .

```
export interface FilterViewModel<T> {
    filters: T
}
```

now i use that by this model :

```
GetAllUsersPaging(items: FilterViewModel<GetAllUserFilter>)
```

and this is items of my models :

```
   export interface GetAllUserFilter {
    blocked: boolean,
    emailConfirmed: boolean,
    isActive: boolean,
    isDeleted: boolean,
    personalVerified: boolean,
    phoneNumberConfirmed: boolean,
    phoneNumber: string
}
```

now i want to search in all filters item and push that in the variable . i write this code but it not worked and not go loop in the all items and just once loop .

```
    async GetAllUsersPaging(items: FilterViewModel<GetAllUserFilter>) {

    let query: any = [];


    [items.filters].forEach((element) => {

        if (!element.phoneNumber) {
            query.push(element);
        } else {
            query.push({ phoneNumber: { $regex: `(.*)${element.phoneNumber}(.*)` } });
        }

    });

}
```

now whats the problem ? how can i loop in all items in `items.filters` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items.filters` looks like an object instead of an array, and I think your idea is loop thought all key of `GetAllUserFilter` and append them, their value to `query` array.

You can use `Object.keys` to get all keys of an object, then loop thought them to check their name and value object the object at the key.

```
async GetAllUsersPaging(items: FilterViewModel<GetAllUserFilter>) {

  const query: any = [];

  Object.keys(items.filters).forEach(key  => {
    const value = items.filters[key as keyof GetAllUserFilter];
    if (key === 'phoneNumber' && value) {
      query.push({ phoneNumber: { $regex: `(.*)${value}(.*)` } });
    } else {
      query.push({ [key]: value }); // ex: { blocked: true }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: when i use your code it show me this error : `MongoError: Unsupported projection option: phoneNumber: { $regex: "(.*)0914(.*)" }`

Comment: `query.push({ phoneNumber: { $regex: new Regex(value) });`